# Reducing memory overhead in IIS setup with shared ASP.NET applications

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I've got three core ASP.NET applications that I need to run. I'm setting up two Windows Server 2008 R2 servers with mirrored IIS 7.5 configurations and then a load balancer to direct traffic and another server to be the state server. That's all setup and working (not in production yet).

We have about 120 clients (and growing) and my setup now is that each client gets their own virtual directory (as a .NET application) off the IIS root. The virtual directory application points to a directory on disk where their own web.config lives to store things like connection strings and some core application parameters. Then off of each client's application there's a virtual directory application for each of the three core ASP.NET apps. So something like this:

```
/ (IIS root)
    /client1    => c:\inetpub\clients\client1
        /app1   => c:\inetpub\applications\app1\current
        /app2   => c:\inetpub\applications\app2\current
        /app3   => c:\inetpub\applications\app3\current
    /client2    => c:\inetpub\clients\client2
        /app1   => c:\inetpub\applications\app1\current
        /app2   => c:\inetpub\applications\app2\current
        /app3   => c:\inetpub\applications\app3\current
```

The 'current' directory is a symlink to the current version being used.

This setup has some advantages

- Automatic segregation of .NET session, application, and authentication info. Zero chance of any cross-application contamination or security problems (e.g. client1 changes the URL to see client2).
- Automatic web.config inheritance so there's no need to go searching on disk for each client's config file. The settings "just work".
- Each client can be (and is) configured to have their own application pool so one client can't cause problems for anyone else with regards to performance.

Disadvantages:

- There is significant memory overhead with having one app pool per client
- Each application instance (e.g. /client1/app1, /client1/app2, /client2/app1, ...) is compiled separately by ASP.NET even though there are only three "real" applications
- There's app pool warmup time overhead. If one client hasn't accessed the server in a while, the first hit has to wait for their worker process to start. I've mitigated this by running all the pools in 32 bit mode.

My biggest issue is the memory consumption. If I use curl to loop over and hit each application at each client, every worker process is using about 100 MB of RAM. That means I'd need 16 GB of server RAM to safely operate. That is nuts considering that the apps themselves really aren't that big or terribly complex. Memory breakdown for each worker process is roughly: Private bytes 70 MB, Working Set 85 MB, WS Shared: 32 MB. Memory is a concern since these are cloud servers where the cost is directly related to RAM usage. Even if it weren't the cost, it still seems nuts to allow memory to be wasted like that.

My first question is: is there anything I can do to configure IIS or ASP.NET to not compile each application instance separately but to realise that the three apps are in fact the exact same code, thus hopefully reducing startup time and perhaps even memory usage? If I do clients * applications * two servers, that's 720 'applications' compiled on disk.

Second question is one of best practices. Is my setup righteous (for lack of a better word)? Is the RAM waste worth it for the sake of code simplicity and security? Is there another way to achieve the benefits of web.config inheritance and session/application/forms auth without having separate applications in this way?

Thinking of the code changes needed to change the setup so there are only three applications and for those applications to become client-aware is rather daunting and kind of gross.

1. Adding {client} to the root of each MVC route (one app isn't MVC so that'd be different)
2. Using {client} to search for and load configuration files stored elsewhere on disk. Perhaps in json format or something.
3. On each request, make sure the {client} hasn't changed, and if it has, clear all session and application variables. De-auth the user to prevent security problems.

I'm not looking for anyone to make up my mind for me, but if anyone has faced similar issues before, it'd be nice to hear about them. Or maybe there will be consensus that I am totally on the wrong track and need to change my code and setup. I think any kind of feedback on the issues would be useful, and certainly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy answer for this question unless you rewrite the whole application as single instance multi-tenant application. Then you will also need to deal with the business and existing service level agreement with the clients. Some customers do not like app pool or database being shared with other customers due to security concern. I suggest to review your service level agreement first and you might find that you actually need to keep it that way.

Comment: BTW, you might actually ease the compiling a bit by signing any shared code or the whole web app into an assembly, package it as a msi file and install it into the GAC of the server.

Comment: Somehow I've made it this far in my career without knowing the "multi-tennant" terminology even though I've been doing it for years. Now I at least have a good term to search for around the web. Thanks! Now that I know what to look for, apparently I'm not the only person having this issue. There's some comfort in that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @airmanx86 for [pointing me in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103506/reducing-memory-overhead-in-iis-setup-with-shared-asp-net-applications#comment12943554_10103506) with multi-tenancy.

I found the following two blog posts from Ben Foster immensely useful in this process:

- [Simple approach to multi-tenancy in ASP.NET MVC](https://web.archive.org/web/20150426120616/http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Simple-approach-to-multi-tenancy-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) (Part 1)
- [Simple approach to multi-tenancy in ASP.NET MVC](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508143009/http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Simple-approach-to-multi-tenancy-in-ASPNET-MVC-Part-2.aspx) (Part 2)

It took a few days of hard work to really understand this and get it setup and refactor my code to be more flexible, but the results are just amazing. Before if I used a `curl` loop to hit a very simple 'debug' page for each client there were a few seconds of startup time, about 100 MB of memory usage, and by the time I hit all the clients, the first ones to have loaded were being swapped out of memory.

Now, I run the same `curl` loop and it's almost instantaneous to hit 100+ applications and my worker process RAM usage is around 150 MB. I am overjoyed!

It's time for me to run, not walk, to converting the rest of my apps to be truly multi-tenant.

Comment: The two blog posts are the same- I am tempted to know what the other one was supposed to be! Oh do you mean parts 1 and 2?